# Как отправить спрятанный текст (спойлер) telebot

Tags: python, telebot, бот, telegram

Всем привет! Есть тг-бот (библиотека pytelegrambotapi). Может ли он прислать пользователю скрытый текст? Или такое не поддерживается?

Я пытался сделать текст скрытым, благодаря спец. символам, но не работает:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Описание: ||Привет||")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да просто юзай MarkdownV2.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Видно ||Не видно||", parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Вот доп. инфа [Ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style)